# Oracle 11g database Auditing

Tags: oracle

I am auditing oracle database application, how can I verify that:

**Database Control files and logs are being multiplexed**

```
SQL > SELECT * FROM V$LOGFILE;
SQL > SELECT * FROM v$controlfile;
```

**Database files and log files are placed on different physical devices.**

```
SQL > SELECT name FROM V$DATAFILE;
SQL > SELECT * FROM V$LOGFILE;
```

Comment: you seem to have the answer to your own question

Comment: From the output how do I check if there are differnet?

Comment: each one of your queries shows the path or folder of the file, you should be able to tell if they are on different disks

Comment: So for LOGFILE if C:/ and CONTROL FILE if D/: then they means comply?

Comment: If all your control files are on the D drive (and the D drive is one physical disk) i would be concerned, just think what would happen if the D drive failed.

Comment: I only have one control files :C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\CONTROL.DBF

Comment: 2         ONLINE
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_2_BX7SC4SL_.LOG
YES

  However my log files are on the same disks       1         ONLINE
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_BX7SC3BZ_.LOG
YES

Comment: that would worry me in production. But as this is an XE environment it's not that big a deal.